# Change in frequency of sound with distance

Tags: waves, acoustics, frequency

If with distance from the emission point, the amplitude reduces, then the energy per unit area decreases.

So if the energy is decreased, how do we get the atoms of medium to vibrate at the same rate? They are given less energy, so they vibrate slowly, so less vibrations per second should be seen, and hence, frequency should go down.
Why doesn't it go down?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both amplitude and maximum velocity decrease as the energy decreases.  The ratio between velocity and amplitude stays the same and this ratio is the frequency.  They move slower but they have less distance to travel so the time for one cycle stays the same.  If you study waves you should have studied the simple harmonic oscillator. This relationship is there, in the equations of motion.